# React + Expressjs URL params returning undefined on get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-fullstack

so I'm trying to make a web application that stores the user. I want to use this user in the back-end to retrieve information. So right now a button is clicked and that calls the back-end, the onClick function currently looks like this.

```
const getBackend = () => {
    let url = new URL('https://http://localhost:4000/backend');
    url.search = new URLSearchParams({
        username: user,
    });
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/prize`, {
        method: "GET",
        url:url,
    });
}
```

and my express.js server looks like this:

```
app.get("/backend", async (req, res) => {
    let user = req.query.username;
    console.log("user");
    res.send(user);
}
```

What happens is that when I *click the button* from the front end with the **getBackend function** the console and browser will log the user as **"undefined"**. However, when I put the link on the *browser directly* as: **http://localhost:4000/prize?username=test3%40something.edu** I successfully get **"test3@something.edu"** working. How can I make the button give me the same as putting it on the browser?

Thank you.

Comment: Show the way you "log the user". `fetch` return a Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you accidently added the https in the url. You should leave off the https and just keep the http

```
const getBackend = () => {
    let url = new URL('http://localhost:4000/backend');
    url.search = new URLSearchParams({
        username: user,
    });
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/prize`, {
        method: "GET",
        url:url,
    });
}
```